# Store JSON using mysql module for Nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, node.js, node-mysql

I need to store a JSON in the column 'data' of this table:

[image]

I tried to store a json but I receive errors, probably due to for quoting...

```
connection.connect();

var query = 'INSERT INTO Forecasts (data, createdAt, updatedAt, OrchardId) VALUES ?';


connection.query(query, [['{"id": 1}', '2017-07-06 16:08:19','2017-07-06 16:08:19',3]],function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].solution);
});

connection.end();
```

**OUTPUT**

> $ npm start
>
> > revo-weather@1.0.0 start /Users/giovannimarino/Desktop/revo-weather
> >     node index.js
>
> {"id":1} INSERT INTO Forecasts (data, createdAt, updatedAt, OrchardId)
>   VALUES ("gio", "2017-07-06 16:08:13", "2017-07-06 16:08:13", 3)
>   MacBook-Pro-di-Giovanni:revo-weather giovannimarino$ npm start
>
> > revo-weather@1.0.0 start /Users/giovannimarino/Desktop/revo-weather
> >     node index.js
>
> /Users/giovannimarino/Desktop/revo-weather/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:79
>           throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
>           ^
>
> Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ''{\"id\": 1}', '2017-07-06 16:08:19', '2017-07-06
>   16:08:19', 3' at line 1
>       at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/Users/giovannimarino/Desktop/revo-weather/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:52:14)
>       at Query.ErrorPacket (/Users/giovannimarino/Desktop/revo-weather/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:77:18)
>       at Protocol._parsePacket (/Users/giovannimarino/Desktop/revo-weather/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:280:23)
>       at Parser.write (/Users/giovannimarino/Desktop/revo-weather/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:75:12)
>       at Protocol.write (/Users/giovannimarino/Desktop/revo-weather/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
>       at Socket. (/Users/giovannimarino/Desktop/revo-weather/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:103:28)
>       at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:210:7)
>       at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:252:12)
>       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:239:11)
>       --------------------
>       at Protocol._enqueue (/Users/giovannimarino/Desktop/revo-weather/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:141:48)
>       at Connection.query (/Users/giovannimarino/Desktop/revo-weather/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:208:25)
>       at Object. (/Users/giovannimarino/Desktop/revo-weather/index.js:19:12)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
>       at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16) npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! revo-weather@1.0.0 start: `node index.js` npm
>   ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the revo-weather@1.0.0
>   start script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There
>   is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /Users/giovannimarino/.npm/_logs/2017-07-14T14_16_03_166Z-debug.log

Comment: Just an opinion, but if you want to persist data in JSON format, check out MongoDB

Answer (score 3):

How about you `JSON.strigify` your json object and then persist it. While pulling back data you can parse it again.

```
connection.connect();

var query = 'INSERT INTO Forecasts (data, createdAt, updatedAt, OrchardId) VALUES ?';


connection.query(query, [[JSON.stringify('{"id": 1}'), '2017-07-06 16:08:19','2017-07-06 16:08:19',3]],function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].solution);
});

connection.end();
```

Comment: I receive this error:
`Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''\"{\\\"id\\\": 1}\"', '2017-07-06 16:08:19', '2017-07-06 16:08:19', 3' at line 1`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use:

```
JSON.stringify(data)
```